Is there a function whose every derivatives converge to 0 in a finite interval with a limit on the rate of convergence?
Specifically, does it exist an infinitely differentiable function $f:R→R$ that meets the following conditions?

The domain contains $[0,+\infty)$.
$f(0)=1$ and $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for $x>0$.
$\dot{f}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$, where $0<a<+\infty$.
$\ddot{f}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$, where $0<a<+\infty$.
$\frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$, where $0<a<+\infty$.
$|\frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}|$ is bounded on $[0,+\infty)$.
Besides, it's better to meet that its higher derivative ${f}^{(n)}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$, where $0<a<+\infty$ and $n>2$.

I made some attempts, but could not fully satisfy the above properties.

Try 1: $f_1(x) = b/(x+b)$, with $b>0$.
It meets all of the above conditions but with $a=+\infty$.

Try 2: $f_2(x)=e^{-x}$. It meets most of the above conditions but with $a=+\infty$. And the 5th condition cannot be met.

Try 3: The functions proposed in the answers of the question.
It meets most of the above conditions besides the 5th and 6th conditions.


Or could we prove that these conditions are in conflict?
Thanks in advance.

What is the relationship between $~f(x), ~\dot{f}(x), ~$ and $\ddot{f}(x) ~?$

Thanks for your attention! $\dot{f}(x)$ denotes the first derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. And $\ddot{f}(x)$ denotes the second derivative of $f(x)$. @user2661923
